# How to create CSV file from SQL?

Tags: postgresql

I am wondering how to create or export a CSV file from SQL? Is there any function for that similar to pgsql2shp?
I would appreciate your ideas, tip or solutions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can give this a try. But i believe there may be some syntax changes depending on the version.

```
COPY (SELECT foo,bar FROM whatever) TO ‘/tmp/dump.csv’ WITH CSV HEADER
```

Comment: I got this message: ERROR:  could not open file "/dump.csv" for writing: Permission denied

What should i do now?

Btw, instead of the query above i wrote:
COPY (SELECT * FROM table1) TO '/dump.csv' WITH CSV HEADER 
because proposed path does not exist.

Comment: Ok. I found out that problem was in path. So I changed path to:
'C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/8.4/data/test.csv' and it works now. Obvoiusly some folders has restrictions.

Answer (score 6):

You can save a complete table as a file using this command:

```
COPY tablename TO STDOUT CSV
```

Ref: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-copy.html

Answer (score 1):

If you use pgAdmin, you can export any query you run to a CSV file.